# create new cols based on a delimiter from a particular column

Tags: kdb

I have a table say tab where there are multiple cols. I am interested to in the column text which is of type C.
Now we want to use text column and split based on delimeter ; and create a new column

So here column name will be rank and its value will be 1 and so on...
How do we that in kdb+?

I had came up with below but i dont want to use it as its hardcoded it to item 6 and so on.. what if the order changes, or if country is missing, then it'll break

```
res:update `$(raze(" *";"=")0:string country) from  update country:(`$";" vs' text)[;6] from res;
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PLEASE provide sample code to create your data when asking a question, a picture doesn't help us.

```
q)t:([]text:("aa=1;bb=XYZ;cc=$1.23";"bb=TUV;dd=3.4%";"aa=foo;cc=10"))
q)t,'(uj/)exec{enlist(!/)"S=;"0:x}'[text]from t
text                   aa    bb    cc      dd
-------------------------------------------------
"aa=1;bb=XYZ;cc=$1.23" ,"1"  "XYZ" "$1.23" ""
"bb=TUV;dd=3.4%"       ""    "TUV" ""      "3.4%"
"aa=foo;cc=10"         "foo" ""    "10"    ""
```

This is the relevant part of the documentation: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/file-text/#key-value-pairs

Comment: my apologies, yes will definitely provide sample query next time. 
Thanks for your quick response and sharing the link.